# Inserting data into InfluxDB from Python Dictionary

Tags: python, influxdb

I currently have a Python script that scrapes a list of servers' web diagnostic page for two values and saves them into a Python dictionary.  Originally I was trying to insert into MySQL, but the way the dictionary was structured it wouldn't let me get historical data using Grafana.  Is there a way to insert a dictionary that would look like this into Influx?

```
server01,value01,value02,date_time
server02,value01,value02,date_time
server03,value01,value02,date_time
server04,value01,value02,date_time
```

The dictionary is generated using a for loop, so the number of servers "could" change, so InfluxDB seems to be the most capable for something like this.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You can use influx-python and insert data to influxdb